# android studio ide internal error occurred nullpointerexception: null

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, mobile-development

My android studio was working just fine, I don't remember updating anything but I must have changed something unknowingly because all of a sudden I'm getting a nullpointerexception with my project and when starting android studio I get the IDE internal error occurred. I tried making a new project and I keep getting the  nullpointerexception: null.
I have tried the methods suggested to other people who asked the same question (updating android studio, clearing the avd folder under android...) and none of them worked for me and that's why I asked this question hoping for a solution that might work for me.

Comment: ignore this and run your project. It'll run perfectly. Don't worry bout internal errors. (At least this worked for me.) :)

Comment: Have same problem on Android Studio 2.3.3